# Associating / linking an array column with another column in the array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, octave

I have an array that has some calcultations done on the second column.  I would like the values from the third column to follow/be linked to the second column.

Test Code:

```
a1= [1,10,-11;
2,70,232;
3,33.2,-33;
4,40,44;]

a2calc=abs(a1(:,2)-max(a1(:,2))) %calculation

a2=[a1(:,1),a2calc,a1(:,3)] %new array
```

Example: 
**original a1 Array**

```
1   10  -11
2   70   232
3   33.2  -33
4   40   44
```

**a2 Array after column 2 calculations looks like this**

```
1   60  -11
2    0   232
3   36.8  -33
4   30   44
```

**I'm trying to get the final array to look like** this (column 3 values follow / are linked to the second column)

```
1   60  232
2    0  -11 
3   36.8  44
4   30   -33
```

What I'm having problems with is I'm not sure if I should use the index values of column 2 and if so how I can get it to look like the final output array I included in the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which rule should be applied to resort the third column?

Comment: @DanielR that's what I'm having problems with I'm not sure if I should use the index values of column 2 and if so how I can get it to look like the final output array I included in the question.

Comment: "column 3 values follow the second column": please explain that. In which sense should they _follow_ the second column?

Comment: @Luis Mendo I updated to say "follow / are linked to the second column"

Comment: but how? it doesn't make any sense. What do you mean with "linked"? Are they sorted in a way? From `a1` to `a3` you changed column 3 without any obvious logic.

Comment: In the second column every row stays at it's place. I recommend you to take pen and paper and do the calculation by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but it looks to me like the logic is:

After calculating the second column, change the order of the third column so that the third column is sorted the same way as the second. To see what I mean:
This represents the two columns, numbered from highest to lowest:

```
A = 1    1
    4    3
    2    2
    3    4
```

If I understand it right,  you want the resulting matrix to be

```
A = 1    1
    4    4
    2    2
    3    3
```

If this is the right logic then you should check out [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) with two outputs. You can use the second output to index the third column.

```
[~, idx] = sort(A(:, 2));
sorted_3 = sort(A(:, 3));

A(idx, 3) = sorted_3;
```

The output from this is:

A =

```
 1.00000    60.00000   232.00000
 2.00000     0.00000   -33.00000
 3.00000    36.80000    44.00000
 4.00000    30.00000   -11.00000
```

Good luck!